# "Fetch the data if it doesn't exist" selector?

Tags: redux, react, redux-saga

Let's say I have a react component like this:

```
const MyComponent = ({data}) => (<div>{JSON.stringify(data)}</div>); 

const myReduxSelector = (state, id) => state.someData[id]; 

export default connect(
    (state, ownProps) => ({
     data: myReduxSelector(state, ownProps.someId)
    })
)(MyComponent);
```

Now this works fine, *if the data already exists*.

What's the tidiest way to handle this, if the data doesn't already exist?

The only way I can really see to to this, to add an onMount/construct function to dispatch an action that will fetch it.

eg.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props); 
        if (!props.data) {
            this.props.fetchData(); 
        }
    }

    render() {
       const {data} = this.props;    
       return <div>{JSON.stringify(data)</div>; 
    }

}

export default connect(
    (state, ownProps) => ({
         data: myReduxSelector(state, ownProps.someId)
     }),
     (dispatch, ownProps) => ({
        fetchData: () => dispatch(createFetchDataAction(ownProps.someId))
     })
)(MyComponent);
```

The problem with this is - say I have lots of components that all do this, it just becomes a pain to write and maintain.

Is there a tidy, established pattern for solving this problem? Use of redux-saga is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a typical scenario for HOC (higher-order-component) or RenderProps if you prefer it that way. The component would receive the action type that needs to be fired and does so on it's `componentWillMount`.

Though it's 2019, so a custom `effect` (React Hook) that dispatches the action from a `FunctionalComponent`would probably be the way to go with the current setup based on the information you provided.